# How to update or reply to a Microsoft Teams message using a webhook?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have searched through the documentation and cannot seem to find a solution for this. I created a webhook into Microsoft Teams channel and used this guide to post a message into the channel:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#post-a-message-to-the-webhook-using-curl

This works quite nicely, but I would also like to make another cURL request to update the message. Is this even possible? What are my options?

I thought the "correlationId"-field would be the solution for creating unique identifiers for my messages but it doesn't seem to work that way:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference#card-fields

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight forward way of updating a message sent by webhook, what you can try is getting the list of messages using [List Channel Messages API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and then taking note of id of the particular message to update, and then use [update message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) Graph API to update.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try that route.

Comment: @bulkware, please accept the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: I will, after I get the chance to test it out :)

Comment: According to the documentation, only the `policyViolation` field can be updated using the Graph API. The contents of the message itself cannot be updated. So this solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it has been added in a subsequent release, as I am able to update the message as long as the correlation id remains the same

```
{ "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
"@type": "MessageCard",
"summary": "OMG Teams Integration",
"correlationId": "407ac8ee-b3d4-4c3d-9af9-0908566fedf7",
"sections": [
{
  "activityTitle": "**Alerts**",
  "activityImage": "https://xxx/_Icon_Color.png",
  "activityText": "Some text"
}
]
}
```

To replace the text, call the same endpoint with the same correlation and new text.

```
{ "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
"@type": "MessageCard",
"summary": "OMG Teams Integration",
"correlationId": "407ac8ee-b3d4-4c3d-9af9-0908566fedf7",
"sections": [
{
  "activityTitle": "**Alerts**",
  "activityImage": "https://xxx/_Icon_Color.png",
  "activityText": "Updated text"
}
]
}
```

Comment: how are you submitting the request? can you provide an example? Thank you

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't seem to be working, is it just another post request?

Comment: I test this way and not work for me .

Comment: @SuperMistaG could you elaborate on how you had it working ? Using curl post twice on the incoming webhook endpoint just generates another message.